# Python DataFrame - Boxplot of a data column (which contains 20+ values in a form of a list)

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn-0.12.x

I am bit new to this.

Consider a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'info':['1a','1b','1a','1b','1a','1b'],'list1': np.random.randint(0, 10, (6,15)).tolist()},index=list('AABBCC'))

print(df)
```

I wish to be able to create a `boxplot`(preferably using `seaborn`), with a "hue" applied to the 'info' column such that the box(or `boxenplot`) plot for each of the index A,B,C are next to one another - in a single plot of `size plt.figure(figsize=X,Y)`.

I am familiar with plotting from `dataframe` where single values per column. However I am struggling to plot it eloquently when there is a list.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) your `list1` series into [long or "tidy" data](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-data) before using [`seaborn.boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "info": ["1a", "1b", "1a", "1b", "1a", "1b"],
        "list1": np.random.randint(0, 10, (6, 15)).tolist(),
    },
    index=list("AABBCC"),
)
df = df.explode(column="list1")
sns.boxplot(data=df, x=df.index, y="list1", hue="info")
plt.show()
```

[image: boxplot]